# Is separability a necessary and sufficient condition for symmetry?

Tags: symmetry

I just wondered about the following issue. Take General Relativity and the Kerr solution. The separability of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation (or equivalently the Klein-Gordon equation in this curved space-time) implies the emergence of the Carter constant. Thus, is separability a condition for a hidden symmetry to happen? If not enough or necessary, what triggers it?